# What happens if a dependent current source does not dissipate/generate energy?

Tags: dc

[image: Circuit With Dependent Current Source]

If that dependent current source doesn't generate/dissipate energy (Power=0) in the given circuit, How do we approach that kind of problems?. I know independent current sources behave like open switches when power upon them are zero (P=0). So should i assume that dependent current sources will behave like open switch as well?

Also another thing that confuses me;

*P=V.I*

Therefore,
V or I has to be 0 but how do we decide whether Voltage Drop on current source is 0 or the current that is created by the current source is 0.

Comment: I think perhaps this is a trick question.  Either it does dissipate power, or you would never see it in a real circuit without a resistance in series.  Put a load in series and it makes perfect sense though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how do we decide whether Voltage Drop on current source is 0

In this circuit you know it is not 0 because there is a voltage source connected in parallel with the CCCS.

In another circuit you would simply solve the circuit, by mesh or nodal analysis or whatever other method you like, and from that find the voltage across the current source the same way you would find the voltage between any other two nodes.

> should i assume that dependent current sources will behave like open switch as well?

You should assume it produces a current equal to \$\alpha\$ times the current in the controlling branch, and let that determine how it interacts with the rest of the circuit.

Comment: Yes that makes a lot of sense. So according to your approach we know that the voltage drop on current source is not zero , therefore from the *P=I.V* can we say that the current which dependent current source produces will be 0? If the answer is ''yes'' then current source doesn't provide any current to the circuit. So shouldn't we ignore its existence without solving? I am sorry if these are too noobish questions :D . I am just trying to make the things clear in my mind.

Comment: @Neverhadagf, you should go through and solve it mathematically (using node analysis will be easiest) first. Then think about your answer and how you could have got there with an initial simplifying assumption.

Answer (score 0):

You can analyze both cases.

If V=0 then the voltage source must be zero, and the current through the resistors will also be zero.

If I=0 then the current through the resistors must also be zero (because I is proportional to that current), so the voltage must also be zero.

There is no non-trivial solution in this case.

Comment: In both cases it will behave like open switch right? Because if the Power is 0 that means it doesn't provide/take anything to/from the circuit

Comment: @Neverhadagf, "Power is 0 that means it doesn't provide/take anything to/from the circuit" Where did you learn that? If that were true you could remove all the ideal wires from your circuit and it would still work --- which is obviously false.

Comment: One could imagine a (different) situation where it is providing current but has no voltage across the terminals. The dependency equation would have to have an offset term.

Comment: @ThePhoton I did say such thing because if P=0 either I=0 or V=0. In case of I=0, source doesn't provide anything to the circuit. In case of V=0 it doesn't use any of the voltage value that the voltage source provides. So in both cases it makes sense for me to replace it with an open switch. Anyway i'll try solve it mathematically and investigate the results and conclude this. Thank you everyone who answered. I can see the things much more clear now.

Comment: @Neverhadagf The case of V=0 does not correspond to an open switch. An open switch forces I=0. A closed switch provides V=0.